# Zoho Creator in iframe adds blank lines - how do we stop that behavior

Tags: iframe, zoho

We use Zoho creator which allows us to generate iframe "code" to embed in html.

When we do that, additional blank lines are added to the end of the displaed results.

You can see what I mean on this page I created to illustrate the issue: 
https://themezz.com/zoho/index.html  - it has 5 lines of text with the iframe tucked it; yet many blank lines are added. View page source please.

Also tried many variations of the height and width tags with negative results.
https://themezz.com/zoho/index2.html

The ultimate goal is to embed that chart into a Wordpress theme, which I have done, but of course all the additional blank lines appear which look like crap. I embedded it in the Wordpress php, as well as tried as a widget, and also ran it through feedburner as RSS THEN into Wordpress with all poor results.

I *think* it's a Zoho issue, but their tech support has not replied nor has anyone in the Zoho support community.

Perhaps someone can think of a solution, or a workaround for eliminating these blank lines.

Appreciate your time.

Comment: Without a reproducible example, it is difficult for other uses to answer your question. Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

Do you want it to look like this
[image]

i have tried it in zoho creator pages ,only change being done is in height attribute

code:

```
<html>
<p>every</p> <p>good</p> <p>boy</p> <p><iframe src="https://creator.zohopublic.com/kyl184/resource-dispatch/view-embed/Embed_page/yRSBBntzf7Au4MrZ6k6rnB1mjD46uYmSpeW1bUdwpVzCFmJKdwn6Ssr7YOs3Aa1A5D261uUXx22aOXAPOdHgxPeJ6BE2rbg3eeSR?" width="800px" height="300px" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe> </p> <p>does</p> <p>fine</p>
```

here is a demo page view from wordpress containing your iframe data
[image]

Comment: YES. Looks like a lower height number fixes things, which was the opposite of what I thought. Appreciate your help.